# Identify XPATH for clicking button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently working on a web scraping project involving the web application of Refinitiv Workspace, a financial data provider. That is, the website isn't publicly available, as it requires login credentials to access.

The goal of my project is to automate the process of downloading text files from each row in a table, as shown in the screenshot.
I want to click (i.e., download) each of the .txt icons associated with the rows. My code is already capable of logging in to the website and navigating to the relevant page with the table.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("Website") ##I onmitted the complete link as it is very long
browser.find_element(By.ID,'AAA-AS-SI1-SE003').send_keys(r"Email")
browser.find_element(By.ID,'AAA-AS-SI1-SE006').send_keys(r"Password")
browser.find_element(By.ID,'AAA-AS-SI1-SE014').click()
browser.get("https://workspace.refinitiv.com/web/Apps/Corp/?s=ADBE.O&st=RIC#/Apps/AdvEvents?profile=COMPANY&dt=ADBE.O&OAPermID=4295905431")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="section0"]/div/div/div/div[9]/div[1]/div/app-download-formatter/coral-button[3]').click() ##This is supposed to click on the txt icon which will lead to a download of the file
```

Could anyone guide me on how to proceed from here? Specifically, I'm struggling with interacting with the icons in the rows to initiate the download of the associated text files.

Thank you

[image: Button I want to click]

[image: HTML structure]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show elements above coral-button? Does coral-button have any #shadow-root or iframe as it's parent?

Comment: Yes, the button seems to have a #shadow-root as its parent.

Comment: So, try to find parent which has `shadow-root` and access it's property, like I described. Be aware, that there can be several shadow-roots as a parents of your button. If you still can't get element, please, provide html structure above coral-button

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this is the correct element that act as button when click?

You can try to select the element with right click and save as global variable (In the developer menu). Then use that variable .click().

Maybe the father or the child is the one with the listener..

Once you have identified the correct element, you can right click the element and copy->Xpath full path

Comment: Thank you. I already tried all the childs and copied their Xpaths. Unfortunately, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your button can be placed in `shadow-root` or iframe, so you don't have direct access to it.

To get it from `shadow-root`, you should get parent element of shadow-root first, access it's `shadow-root` property and search for button.

Example:

```py
first_level_frame = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'AppFrame')
driver.switch_to.frame(first_level_frame)
second_level_frame = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'contentframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(second_level_frame)
third_level_frame = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'AppFrame')
driver.switch_to.frame(third_level_frame)
fourth_level_frame = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'contentframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(fourth_level_frame)
fifth_level_frame = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'AppFrame')
driver.switch_to.frame(fifth_level_frame)
sixth_level_frame = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[src*="AdvEvents"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(sixth_level_frame)
seventh_level_frame = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'AppFrame')
driver.switch_to.frame(seventh_level_frame)
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'emerald-grid').shadow_root.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'coral-button')[2]
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, `app_formatter = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'app-download-formatter')` returns `NoSuchElementException`. Please see the more extensive html structure in my original post. I assume the error is due to multiple shadow-roots?

Comment: @xxgaryxx try to get shadow-root from element `emerald-grid`. From updated structure only it has shadow-root.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that the shadow-root itself is rooted in an iframe (see updated post).

Comment: I see that iframe is placed in another iframe. Can you provide also upper frame?

Comment: Sure, I attached a screenshot showing the top level iFrame

Comment: Thanks, entering the iframes works just fine. However, I still get an `NoSuchElementException` when trying to enter the shadow-root.

Comment: Can you make screenshots from `emerald-grid` to `coral-button` html structure?

Comment: I have added it to the original post :)

Comment: @xxgaryxx looks fine there. And now. plz, add last one - from frame with id `AppFrame` to `emerald-grid`

Comment: Done. It appears that the iframe structure is more complex than I thought. I count a total of 7 nested frames before the emerald-grid. I didn't manage to switch to the one without an ID (marked with the red arrow). Maybe this is why I can't access the shadow-root.

Comment: @xxgaryxx try updated answer snippet.

Comment: Thanks. Still not able to switch to level six as the frame can't be found. I highly appreciate the effort you are putting into this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255053/discussion-between-yaroslavm-and-xxgaryxx).